# How do you speed up loading many partials through an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Loading partials is very slow for some reason if I'm doing an ajax request. For example in a brand new Rails 5.1.4 app, I have something like this:

recipes/index.html.erb

```
<% 100.times do %>
   <%= render "abc" %>
<% end %>
```

recipes/_abc.html.erb

```
Lorem Ipsum
```

My routes.rb has:

```
get "/recipes" => "recipes#index"
```

Now when I call the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url:  "/recipes",
   dataType: 'text',
});
```

Every partial is loaded very slowly (compared to going to the page directly without ajax). That is, I see these lines in my console:

```
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered recipes/_abc.html.erb (0.0ms)
```

Each line takes over 1 second to process (despite what the time in the parenthesis says). If I do a reload on the browser instead of an ajax request (or if I click on a link to the /recipes page), each line takes a fraction of a second to load.

Is there a faster way to load those partials through an ajax request?

Comment: reload button cannot really be used as a benchmark since that will almost definitely be local cache that is serving the page. Also I am assuming you are running this in a development environment which will be slower and will try and load the assets for that page as well which are not compiled.

Comment: If I link to the /recipes page and click on that link, I don't run into the slow load issues. The partials load in a fraction of a second compared to over a second with the ajax request. Do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: do you have turbolinks? (seems likely in a new rails 5 app) if so we are still talking about caching

Comment: maybe the problem can also be associated with your system, as by ajax 100 calls are going to your server hence increase in processing time.

Comment: I do have turbolinks on from the default Rails app generator. I'll uninstall it and see if I get the same issues.

Comment: I removed turbolinks and still have the same issues unfortunately.

Comment: I tried it with 20, 10, and 5 partials instead of the 100, and I still have the same issues. Each partial takes much longer to load using an ajax request than without an ajax request.

Comment: I don't know your issue, but you should place the iterator inside the partial and pass the partial the numeric value instead of rendering 100 partials, you can render 1 partial with 100 inline renderings? I think you'll see a performance increase.

Comment: I actually have a page with many different partials scattered throughout a page. It doesn't use any iterator to load partials because every partial is different. I just wanted to demonstrate a page with many partials as an example.